# Glassfish: Error processing EjbDescriptor java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: deployment, jar, ejb, glassfish-3

I have a JEE6 application with several ejbs that each reference client jars.  For most of these I am having no issue whatsoever getting them deployed to my Glassfish 3.1.2 instance.  I have one however, that works fine until I reference it from my business layer application.  There I instantiate an object from the client just like I do in the all the other where it works perfectly.  Only when I reference this particular client jar in the application and then attempt to deploy I get the following from Glassfish:

```
[#|2012-11-08T08:38:22.773-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while deploying the app [rpavis-app-im-1.0-SNAPSHOT]|#]

[#|2012-11-08T08:38:22.773-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error processing EjbDescriptor
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing EjbDescriptor
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EjbDescriptor.visit(EjbDescriptor.java:2578)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EjbBundleDescriptor.visit(EjbBundleDescriptor.java:734)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.Application.visit(Application.java:1765)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.validate(ApplicationArchivist.java:830)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openWith(ApplicationArchivist.java:277)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:827)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:769)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:462)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:403)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:235)
... 39 more
|#]

[#|2012-11-08T08:38:22.782-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while deploying the app [rpavis-app-im-1.0-SNAPSHOT] : Error processing EjbDescriptor
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:462)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:403)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EjbDescriptor.visit(EjbDescriptor.java:2578)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EjbBundleDescriptor.visit(EjbBundleDescriptor.java:734)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.Application.visit(Application.java:1765)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.validate(ApplicationArchivist.java:830)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openWith(ApplicationArchivist.java:277)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:827)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:769)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]
```

I have checked everywhere I know to check and am a total loss.  I feel like I am missing a configuration somewhere but after 2 days I just don't know where.  Can anyone see anything in this error that would help me determine where to even look?

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer.  It turns out I had a reference to a piece I had deleted in the ejb-jar.xml of the EJB.  The particular reference was only consumed by the business layer application and so was not processed until I made that change.  Bottom line, if you have deployment errors, look in the ejb-jar.xml configuration files of the root of the issue and you will likely find your answer there.